# UML, diagrama de fluxo entre páginas

Tags: uml, diagrama

Lembro de ter visto algo parecido na faculdade, mas devido já ter passado muito anos me esqueci.

Qual diagrama devo usar para representar o fluxo entre páginas?

Seria semelhante para representar a estrutura geral do website. Exemplo: na página X o usuário pode ter acesso a tais outras páginas. Como se trata de um sistema web, dependendo do perfil do usuário ele pode ter acesso a página e eu posso diferenciar no diagrama com uma cor relativa ao perfil que tem acesso. É mais ou menos isso, para eu poder documentar as páginas e o fluxo.

Comment: Seu objetivo é representar o fluxo de dados entre certas páginas, a estrutura geral do website ou o que? Porque, dependendo do objetivo, dá pra usar um ou outro diagrama UML. Por exemplo, você poderia usar o diagrama de sequência para representar a ordem planejada em que o usuário navega pelo site (muito embora mais comumente se use pra isso wireframes - [leia esta outra pergunta para mais informações](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21677/73)). Se você quer representar os "gatilhos" que fazem as páginas serem trocadas, talvez o Diagrama de Estados seja mais interessante.

Comment: Este "resumo" que eu achei agora pode lhe ser útil: http://www.profissionaisti.com.br/2011/07/os-principais-diagramas-da-uml-resumo-rapido/

Comment: Eu apostei no diagrama de atividade, pois me parece isso que ele está procurando.

Comment: Poderia dar um exemplo do quer fazer? o fluxo teria condicionais? informe mais detalhes.

Comment: Luiz Vieira, seria tipo para representar a estrutura geral do website. Exemplo: na página X o usuário pode ter acesso a tais outras páginas. Como se trata de um sistema web, dependendo do perfil do usuário ele pode ter acesso a página e eu posso diferenciar no diagrama com uma cor relativa ao perfil que tem acesso. É mais ou menos isso, para eu poder documentar as páginas e o fluxo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Após a sua edição, ficou mais claro entender o que você precisa. Nesse caso, eu não acho que um Diagrama de Sequência seja a melhor escolha. O diagrama de sequência modela as comunicações (ou transições, no seu caso) *ao longo do tempo* entre as entidades envolvidas. Assim, o seu grande uso é representar a sequência lógica em que as ações, geralmente em um caso de uso específico, se realizam por todos os envolvidos (usuários e componentes de um sistema).

Pelo que eu entendi, o seu interesse é mais no sentido de representar duas coisas:

1. A estrutura lógica do website, isto é, quais páginas estão ligadas a quais outras páginas
2. Propriedades de certas transições, como por exemplo, se apenas um perfil é capaz de fazer/permitir certa transição.

Assim, eu concordo mais com [a resposta do colega @rray](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/76727/73), sobre o uso do [Diagrama de Estados](http://www.inf.ufpr.br/silvia/ES/UML/pdf/DiagEstadosAl.pdf). Nele você pode representar cada página como um estado do seu sistema, e nas transições adicionar informações (até mesmo a cor, que você mesmo sugeriu) para indicar suas propriedades.

Wireframes, que eu [mencionei em comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/76725/uml-diagrama-de-fluxo-entre-p%C3%A1ginas/76751#comment156703_76725), seriam mais úteis se você quiser entrar em um nível de detalhe maior (mas não final - isto é, de muito baixo nível) a respeito de quais áreas de cada página deverão permitir as transições. Isso te ajuda não somente a planejar as transições como também outros aspectos da interação com o usuário. Nesse tipo de diagrama, mais informal, você pode desenhar as setas de transição partindo de áreas específicas de um rascunho da tela, para por exemplo indicar se o usuário deve sempre clicar em uma mesma região para navegar, em colunas laterais para ter acesso a ferramentas, etc.

Cabe notar que apesar de eu achar que o Diagrama de Sequencias não é o mais apropriado, isso não quer dizer que você não possa utilizá-lo. Você provavelmente só terá que fazer vários deles, para cada *cenário* de navegação. E, mesmo eu respondendo esta sua pergunta com o melhor que eu consigo inferir com base na minha experiência, eu ainda acho que ela é um pouco baseada em opinião, pois não há verdadeiramente uma resposta mais correta.

Comment: concordo com a sua visão.

Comment: O Wireframe me agradou bastante para o que eu preciso, boa dica! Porém, eu imaginei em termos de documentação e padrões de projeto usando UML. É perfeitamente útil Wireframes para o que eu preciso, unir todos e montar o fluxo.

Comment: UML é apenas uma ferramenta, uma linguagem visual criada para auxiliar a modelagem de sistemas orientados a objeto. Ela tem a vantagem de ser um padrão mais amplamente conhecido no desenvolvimento de software, mas Wirefremes (que também é uma linguagem visual) também são bastante populares entre o design de interfaces. Como qualquer um tem seus guias e você pode mesmo assim customizá-los para a sua necessidade, na prática você escolhe e usa o que achar melhor pra documentar o seu projeto.

Comment: E, btw, assim como para a UML, também existem para Wireframes uma série de ferramentas de apoio à criação. Por exemplo: https://webdesignledger.com/tools/10-excellent-tools-for-creating-web-design-wireframes (eu particularmente gosto bastante da Balsamiq Mockups e da Cacoo).

Comment: Tomei a liberdade de corrigir a URL. Removi apenas a palava "Novo" pois mudaram o diretório.

Answer (score 1):

Seria o [Diagrama de Sequencia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagrama_de_sequ%C3%AAncia).

> O **Diagrama de Sequência** é uma das ferramentas UML usadas para
>   representar interações entre objetos de um cenário, realizadas através
>   de operações ou métodos (procedimentos ou funções). Este diagrama é
>   construído a partir do Diagrama de Casos de Usos. Primeiro, define-se
>   qual o papel do sistema (Use Cases), depois, é definido como o
>   software realizará seu papel (Sequência de operações).

fonte wikipedia

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Para exibir essas informações existem dois candidatos, são elas o diagrama de estados ou de atividades.

**Diagrama de estado** ou máquina de estados serve para exibir transições de objetos, sistemas ou protocolos.

**Diagrama de atividades**, serve para modelar fluxos de trabalhos, processos algoritmos, muito parecido com um fluxograma a diferença é que o último não suporta atividades paralelas.