# Mapeamento entre user stories e casos de uso

Tags: arquitetura-de-software, engenharia-de-software, metodologia-ágil, casos-de-uso

Quando fazemos a análise de requisitos para desenvolver um sistema é comum utilizar casos de uso para descrever o funcionamento requerido. No caso eu estou falando dos casos de uso escritos por extenso e não dos diagramas. Em geral, os casos de uso contém os passos que um usuário do sistema deve tomar para fazer alguma coisa.

Por outro lado, as user stories também descrevem funcionalidades, mas de uma forma mais resumida. Em geral elas tem o formato:

> Como um [*tipo de usuário*] eu quero [*objetivo*] para que [*motivo*].

Apesar de uma user story deixar claro que uma funcionalidade é requisitada no sistema por seus usuários, ela não da ideia nenhuma de como o sistema deve fazer isso, enquanto que os casos de uso dão essa ideia.

Nesse caso a impressão inicial é que: uma user story é só uma forma de registrar a existência de um requisito sem muitos detalhes, enquanto que um caso de uso é a documentação do resultado de pensarmos em como aquele requisito de fato deveria funcionar na prática.

Esse raciocínio é correto? Realmente devemos estabelecer essa relação entre user stories e casos de uso, considerando que para cada caso de uso corresponde uma user story que é uma descrição "por cima" daquele caso de uso?

Como user stories e casos de uso devem se relacionar?

Answer (score 5):

> Esta é uma tradução livre da postagem original de Courtney, do blog
>   Boost Agile ([*Use cases vs user stories in Agile
>   development*](http://www.boost.co.nz/blog/2012/01/use-cases-or-user-stories/),
>   18 de janeiro de 2012, [www.boost.co.nz](http://www.boost.co.nz/)).

**TL;DR – *User stories* não são a mesma coisa que casos de uso. Por si só, as *user stories* não provêem os detalhes que o time precisa pra fazer o seu trabalho. O processo Scrum permite que esses detalhes emerjam organicamente (em grande parte), removendo a necessidade de se escrever casos de uso.**

### As *user stories* são a mesma coisa que casos de uso?

Quando estamos fazendo o nosso workshop "*Writing Great Agile User Stories*", eu frequentemente recebo a pergunta "Mas então, as *user stories* são a mesma coisa que casos de uso?". Comumente é um analista de negócios quem faz essa pergunta; eles estão acostumados a trabalhar com casos de uso, e se perguntam onde os casos de uso se encaixam em um projeto Scrum e se são substituídos por uma *user story*.

Procurando pela web, existe um consenso de que casos de uso e *user stories* não são intercambiáveis:

- Alistair Cockburn: [A user story is to a use case as a gazelle is to a gazebo.](http://alistair.cockburn.us/A+user+story+is+to+a+use+case+as+a+gazelle+is+to+a+gazebo)
- ExtremeProgramming.org: [User stories serve the same purpose as use cases but are not the same.](http://www.extremeprogramming.org/rules/userstories.html)
- Mike Cohn: [User stories aren’t use cases.](http://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/articles/27-advantages-of-user-stories-for-requirements)

A minha resposta padrão é que as *user stories* são centradas no resultado e no benefício da coisa que se está descrevendo, enquanto que os casos de uso são mais granulares, e descrevem como o sistema irá agir. E então eu digo "Tenha paciência - logo tudo ficará claro". Mas eu acho que já é tempo de aprofundar nesse assunto.

### Casos de uso e *user stories*

Vamos começar por algumas definições.

Uma [*user story*](http://www.boost.co.nz/blog/agile/user-stories/) é uma descrição curta de algo que os seus clientes farão quando entrar em seu website ou utilizar sua aplicação/software, focada no valor ou no resultado que eles obterão quando fizerem isso. Elas são escritas do ponto de vista da pessoa utilizando o website ou aplicação, e em uma linguagem que os seus clientes utilizariam.

Uma *user story* é comumente escrita no formato [canonizado por Mike Cohn](http://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/topics/user-stories): Como um [ator] eu quero [ação] de forma que [resultado] (no original em inglês, *As an [actor] I want [action] so that [achievement]*). Assim, por exezmplo: Como um membro do Flickr, eu quero configurar diferente níveis de privacidade para as minhas fotos, de forma que eu possa controlar quem vê cada uma das minhas fotos.

Um [caso de uso](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caso_de_uso) é uma descrição de um conjunto de interações entre um sistema e um ou mais atores (onde "ator" podem ser pessoas ou outros sistemas: por exemplo, tanto compradores online e o PagSeguro podem ser atores). Eles costumam ser criados como documentos, e geralmente incluem o seguinte tipo de informação:

- Título do caso de uso
- Análise racional/descrição/objetivo
- Ator/usuário
- Precondições (as coisas que precisam já ter ocorrido no sistema)
- Roteiro padrão ou principal cenário de sucesso (o que comumente acontecerá, descrito como uma série de passos)
- Roteiros alternativos ou extensões (variações dos casos acima ou casos excepcionais)
- Pós-condições (o que o sistema terá feito ao final dos passos)

Em uma olhadela rápida, casos de uso parecem um jeito muito melhor de escrever requisitos do que *user stories*. Como um time será capaz de implementar algo tão insubstancial como "Como um membro do Flickr, eu quero configurar diferente níveis de privacidade para as minhas fotos, de forma que eu possa controlar quem vê cada uma das minhas fotos"? Não serão necessários alguns minuciosos casos de uso para detalhar os requisitos do sistema? E é nesse ponto em que geralmente alguém no workshop faz a fatídica pergunta.

A escrita de casos de uso para detalhar *user stories* em projetos Agile não é nenhuma novidade (veja [aqui](http://breathingtech.com/2009/writing-use-cases-for-agile-scrum-projects/) e [aqui](http://blog.casecomplete.com/post/Agile-Use-Cases-in-Four-Steps.aspx)). Mas fica claro, conforme progredimos no workshop, que *user stories* são apenas o início do processo de entendimento do que o time está produzindo, e que, ao final do curso, cobre tudo o que um caso de uso teria informado, mas de uma maneira orgânica.

### Critérios de aceitação

*User stories* não são somente frases únicas. O *product owner* também escreve [critérios de aceitação](http://www.boost.co.nz/blog/agile/acceptance-criteria/), que definem os limites de uma *user story* e são utilizados para confirmar quando ela está completa e funcionando como pretendido. Por exemplo, se esta é a sua *user story* "Como um participante de conferência, eu quero poder me registrar online, de forma que eu o faça rapidamente e reduza a papelada", os critérios de aceitação poderiam incluir:

- Um usuário não pode submeter um formulário sem completar todos os campos obrigatórios.
- A informação do formulário é armazenada em um banco de dados dos registros.
- A proteção contra spam está funcionando.
- O pagamento pode ser feito via cartão de crédito.
- Um email de confirmação é enviado para o usuário após a submissão do formulário.

A escrita dos critérios de aceitação é o primeiro passo para a produção dos detalhes da sua *user story*.

### *Sprints planning meetings*

Nas [reuniões para planejamento de uma sprint](http://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/pages/15-agile-training-on-sprint-planning-meeting), o *product owner* apresenta as *user stories* a partir do topo do seu *backlog* (isto é, as funções de mais alta prioridade) e o time se compromete com as *stories* que completarão na sprint.

Conforme o *product owner* apresenta as *stories*, o time faz perguntas para ajudar no entendimento detalhado delas e dos critérios de aceitação. Suposições são rapidamente confirmadas ou corrigidas, e qualquer ambiguidade sobre os requerimentos começam a desaparecer.

Esse processo de eliminação de suposições e ambiguidade continua conforme o time estima as *stories* (se cinco pessoas no mesmo time classificam uma *story* como 2 e uma pessoa classifica-a como 5, então provavelmente há algumas questões que precisam ser respondidas). E é repetido conforme o time escreve as tarefas individuais de cada *story*.

### *Standups*

Nós temos sido sortudos com os nossos projetos Scrum, pois nossos *product owners* têm se comprometido em fazer as reuniões de *standup* com os times. Esta é outra oportunidade para o time fazer perguntas e também ajudar o *product owner* a ficar ciente das restrições, problemas e oportunidades que se apresentam conforme o desenvolvimento da *story* progride.

### *Wireframing*

Eu faço [*wireframes*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21677/73) de alguns dos nossos projetos, geralmente começando por conversar com o *product owner* sobre a *story* e, algumas verzes, partindo de alguns rascunhos em papel ou no quadro. Eu transformo esses rascunhos em *wireframes*, quando então costuma ocorrer algumas interações rápidas com o *product owner* conforme fazemos perguntas, obtemos o feedback de outras pessoas e (quando possível) conseguimos espaço para fazer um ou outro teste com o usuário usando o *wireframe*.

Mais recentemente eu tenho começado a revisar os *wireframes* iniciais com os designers e os desenvolvedores trabalhando nas *stories*. Isso ajuda a apontar qualquer questão que eles possam ter, assim como também restrições que eu possa ainda não estar ciente. Após a aprovação dos *wireframes* pelo *product owner*, eu repasso informação novamente aos designers e desenvolvedores se necessário.

### Design e desenvolvimento

Ainda que grande parte dos detalhes tenham sido tratados durante a criação dos *wireframes*, pode surgir mais alguma coisa durante este estágio e, frequentemente, outras questões surgem para o *product owner* sobre como exatamente ele ou ela quer que o *backend* do sistema se comporte. A [programação em pares](http://www.boost.co.nz/blog/development/pair-programming-when-and-why/) é útil aqui, porque dois pares de olhos sobre um pedaço de funcionalidade significa que existirão ainda mais questões e clarificações.

Nenhuma *user story* é submetida para aceitação pelo *product owner* até que os critérios de aceitação estejam satisfeitos e a ["definição de conclusão"](http://www.scrumalliance.org/articles/106-definition-of-done-a-reference) seja alcançada.

### No geral

Isso tudo pode soar como um processo moroso. Mas na realidade é tudo o que um time Scrum faz ao longo do dia. Ao invés de uma pessoa só trabalhar sobre casos de uso, todo o time trabalha em conjunto para fazer emergir e para satisfazer todos os requisitos. O *product owner* pode refinar os critérios de aceitação originais em resposta a novas informações obtidas ao longo do progresso das *user stories*.

### E, finalmente, em conclusão

Há exceções, claro - e há momentos em que a pesquisa avançada proporcionada pelos casos de uso é importante (eu tenho uma postagem a esse respeito no forno). Mas o meu conselho seria: não comece a escrever casos de uso até que o seu time especificamente peça por eles. E se o seu time não pedir por eles, gaste algum tempo em uma avaliação [retrospectiva](http://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/pages/54-sprint-retrospective) dos "o quês" que eles não estão obtendo do processo atual (por exemplo: os critérios de aceitação estão claros?; o *product owner* está indisponível?; estamos trabalhando com documentação ruim de outro sistema?; etc). Só então decida, juntamente com o time, como corrigir a raíz do problema.